# How do I convert an array of UnsafeMutablePointer<Double> to an array of Double?

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

I have created an array like this

```
var outputReal = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.allocate(capacity: numeroDados)
```

Now I need to convert that to an array of `Double`.

I can convert that using something like this:

```
var newArray : [Double] = []

for i in 0..<n {
  newArray[i] = outputReal
}
```

But I remember seeing on a page another method of doing this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Details

- Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500), Swift 5.1

### Solution 1

```
extension UnsafeMutablePointer {
    func toArray(capacity: Int) -> [Pointee] {
        return Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: self, count: capacity))
    }
}
```

### Usage of the solution 1

```
var array = [3.9, 7.7, 11.1, 1.11, 1.02, 3.3, 3.9, 0]
let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.allocate(capacity: array.count)
pointer.initialize(from: &array, count: array.count)
print(pointer.toArray(capacity: array.count))
```

### Solution 2

```
extension Array {
    init(pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Element>, count: Int) {
        let bufferPointer = UnsafeBufferPointer<Element>(start: pointer, count: count)
        self = Array(bufferPointer)
    }
}
```

### Usage of the solution 2

```
var array2 = [3.9, 7.7, 11.1, 1.11, 1.02, 3.3, 3.9, 0]
let pointer2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.allocate(capacity: array.count)
pointer2.initialize(from: &array, count: array.count)
print(Array(pointer: pointer2, count: array.count))
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I have changed the accepted answer to yours.

Answer (score 8):

First create an `UnsafeBufferPointer<Double>` referencing the same memory area. That is a `Collection` so that you can create and initialize  an array from that memory:

```
let bufPtr = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: outputReal, count: numeroDados)
let newArray = Array(bufPtr)
```

Alternatively, allocate an `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` (which holds both the address and the size of the allocated memory) in the first place:

```
let numeroDados = 10

let outputReal = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Double>.allocate(capacity: numeroDados)
outputReal.initialize(repeating: 0.0)

let newArray = Array(outputReal)
```

In both cases the values are *copied* to the array's element storage, so you'll have to release the allocated memory eventually.

Comment: Brilliant! That's it! Do you know where I can read about this pointer/buffer safe/unsafe/mutable stuff that explains it well? Anyway thanks!!!!!

Comment: Thank you, you helped me realise that I never needed an `Array`, but rather a collection / `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` over an `UnsafeMutablePointer`. This gets rid of an `Array` init followed by an unsightly redundant `withUnsafeMutableBytes`!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to convert the Pointer to double to an Array of double??

You shouldn't cast a pointer to double to array of double in swift since array in swift is not necessarily the same as a C array. Instead, you copy the contents into the new array. A "low-level" way to do it is

```
var pointerToDoubles = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.allocate(capacity: 10)
var newArray = Array<Double>(repeating: 0, count: 10)
_ = newArray.withContiguousMutableStorageIfAvailable {
  UnsafeMutableRawPointer($0.baseAddress!).copyMemory(from: x, byteCount: MemoryLayout<double>.size * 10)
}
```

Please keep in mind this is *not* safe and will crash if you made some mistakes, for example your new array is too small or if your pointer don't not have as many elements you expecting.